# Error while generating the build for angular application. "Cannot find name 'Omit'."

Tags: angular, build, aws-amplify

I am getting build error for angular application after upgrading amplify version. Can someone please let me know the probable cause for this. This is happening after updating the amplify version to "aws-amplify": "^3.2.3". Any help will be highly appreciated.

error: node_modules/@aws-amplify/datastore/lib-esm/types.d.ts(97,38): error TS2304: "Cannot find name 'Omit'."

Commands:

- npm install
- npm install -g @angular/cli
- ng build --configuration=dev

````
    "name": "test-website",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^7.2.5",
        "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.2",
        "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/material": "^7.3.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
        "aws-amplify": "^3.2.3",
        "aws-amplify-angular": "^3.0.2",
        "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
        "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
        "@angular/cli": "~7.3.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "^4.2.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.11.0",
        "typescript": "~3.2.2"
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade `aws-amplify-angular` as well if it is required. Your issue is most likely (I would think), that your TypeScript version is too old (3.2.2). In order to upgrade your TypeScript version, you would have to upgrade Angular as well because newer versions of TypeScript are not guaranteed to work with older versions of Angular.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I upgrade  "aws-amplify-angular" to same version of "aws-amplify"? Can you please help me with the Typescript and angular versions as well.

Comment: I think you can update aws-amplify to the same version. Updating angular is tricky and a big process. Start with this guide from the Angular team. https://update.angular.io/